# Visual Studio - Copy files from Class Library project to Web Site

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project

I have a `LICENSE` and a `NOTICE` file in a C# Class Library project I'd like to include in a Web Site (not Web Application) project into the `/bin` folder. I can copy them fine into standard project types by setting *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy Always* in their properties, but Web Site projects don't seem to respect this flag.

Is there any way to do this without custom build steps? Making changes to the Class Library rather than the Web Site would be preferable, but not imperative.

Using Visual Studio Professional 2012